# Rest Template -how to retrieve raw POST request String before it's being sent

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

For debugging purposes , I need to retrieve the raw POST request of an

```
restTemplate.postForObject
```

method , is there any way to obtain it before it get send?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache HttpComponents as the underlying HTTP client library for [`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), you could simply add the following to your `application.properties` file and you are good to go:

```
logging.level.org.apache.http=DEBUG
```